# insert a item in to masnory jquery

Tags: magento, jquery-masonry

In a products listing page of magento, i used the masonry and it is working good. But now i want to add a div having some text in the masonry area. I tried this and i get the result, but it break masonry item. My used code...

```
  <?php if ($category_nameplace == round($_collectionSize/2)): ?>
    <div class="item">
      <h2 class="productcategory-name"><?php echo $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getName() ?></h2>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

This above code is used for insert extra item to the masonry area. In the above code i count the items number and as i got the middle number i insert my div in to bellow written area

```
<div id="basic" class="products-grid unstyled thubmnails js-masonry">
          <?php $category_nameplace = 0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
          <?php $category_nameplace++; ?>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(rand(135,400)); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            <div class="caption">
              <h2 class="product-name product-info"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h2>
              <h2 class="product-info"><?php echo "Dimension:".$_product->getDimension(); ?></h2>
              <h2 class="product-info"><?php echo $_product->getPrice(); ?></h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: please share solution